# Windows 7 Internet Explorer 10 Start up page issues

Tags: windows-7

I've been having this nagging and annoying issue with my IE10, though not a serious one.
I'm on Win7 64bit using IE10. Ok here's what happend? 2 days ago my usual home page did not load
when I start up my IE. Instead another china website appear. http://www.hao123.com/?tn=29065018_59_hao_pg.

I've tried changing startup page on my internet options, resetting to default settings...etc. Nothing works. Even when my startup page is my homepage in the settings, it will always go back to the above china webpage everytime I start my IE.

Are there any solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to identify the program which set your homepage to this. If you can't uninstall the browser and reinstall or download Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, not sure this covers the problem outside of basic common sense. This would be a good answer if you included information on how to determine what program changed the homepage